# Is there a way to run gherkin lint for committed files?

Tags: bdd, lint, gherkin

I'm using gherkin-lint for my wdio/cucumber-framework and I would like to run the gherkin lint for the committed files only.

I have tried using the lint command and it does for all the files, not only the committed files ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not averse to using another gherkin linter, try reformat-gherkin together with pre-commit. Their repo has instructions: https://github.com/ducminh-phan/reformat-gherkin

If this is too much of a change for your workflow, here's a guide to using gherkin-lint using a git hook, although it's many more steps and won't be reproduced for your collaborators: https://qaankush.medium.com/governance-of-cucumber-projects-using-git-hooks-and-gherkin-lint-69e199045695